# Document required for German National Visa application

Tags: phd, funding, germany

I have recently been offered a PhD scholarship in a funded project in University of Duisburg Essen, and I want to apply for visa for the same. the issue is the lab I want to join does not have any Non-EU student as of now and the lab's administrative staff is asking me for what document is required for my Visa application. I want to know what information should I ask for to be written in the Document. And also what other documents should I prepare.

I tried searching on google and here and could gather the following documents:

1. Travel health insurance poilcy
2. Accommodation proof
3. my Bachelors and Masters academic transcritps
4. Blocked account??? (since I have a scholarship offer do I really need this)

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Have you contacted the issuing authority? They will have a precise list.

Comment: issuing authority would be the embassy in this case?

Comment: Also check out Euraxess.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't trust google for legal advise!!!!

Instead ask the international office of the university you want to attend. Even if the lab has no experience with non-EU students, the university as a whole certainly has. For Duisburg-Essen look here: https://www.uni-due.de/international/index_en.shtml

Comment: ok I'll write an email to the international office immidiately

Comment: thank you.. they were the most helpful afterall.. :)